# Hello, tell me how to implement data output from a database using Entity Framework in a Listbox WPF MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

With the ability to view details through SelectItem...I do not understand how to binding them correctly ... Listbox exclusively for data output ... And I need that when you click on the menu item on the side, information from the database appears

XAML of listbox

```
<ListBox Height="800" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfilesList}"></ListBox>
```

MyOutputClass

```
using ExperimentProjectt.DB_DIRECT;
using ExperimentProjectt.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExperimentProjectt.Services
{
    public class ProfilesSystem
    {
        public DBContextClass _context = new();
        public List<User> GetAllUsers ()
        {
            List<User> allusers =  _context.Userss.ToList();
            return allusers;
        }
}
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
using ExperimentProjectt.DB_DIRECT;
using ExperimentProjectt.Entities;
using ExperimentProjectt.Services;
using ExperimentProjectt.ViewModels.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExperimentProjectt.ViewModels
{
    public class ProfilesViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ProfilesSystem _profilesSystem;
        public ProfilesViewModel()
        {
            _profilesSystem = new ProfilesSystem();
        }

        private List<User> profileslist;

        public List<User> ProfilesList
        {
            get
            {
                return profileslist = _profilesSystem.GetAllUsers();
            }
            set
            {
                profileslist = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection already has intefaces: INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public ObservableCollection<User> ProfilesList;

ProfilesList = new ObservableCollection<User>(_profilesSystem.GetAllUsers());

private User selectedItem;
public User SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set 
    { 
        selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

then:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfilesList}"></ListBox>
```

example of data output:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Username}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Age}"/>
</StackPanel>
```